# Accessing method in another namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to, from my controller, access a method in a model that is in another namespace and the only way I could do this was to make the method static. Is this the right way to do it, or is there any neater approach?

#### PagesController.php (controller):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Helpers\ConnectedHost;


class PagesController extends Controller
{

    /* 
     * REMOVED CODE HERE FOR READABILITY 
     * Below is where I instantiate the "connectedHost"-object
     */
    $hosts[$hostKey] = new ConnectedHost($hostAttributes['ipv4'], $hostAttributes['mac']);
}

/* REMOVED CODE HERE FOR READABILITY AS WELL */
```

#### ConnectedHost.php (helper-file):

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class ConnectedHost
{
    public $ipv4, $mac;

    public function __construct($ipv4, $mac)
    {
        $this->ipv4 = $ipv4;
        $this->mac = $mac;
        // This is where I call the getName-function staticly,
        $this->name = \App\Host::getName();
    }
}
```

#### Host.php (model):

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Host extends Model
{
    // The method below is declared static
    public static function getName()
    {
        $name = 'wenzzzel';

        return $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a sample of your code. As an advise, check this guide to learn how to improve the quality of your questions: [ask]

Comment: I've updated my question with samples from my code and some comments to further explain which parts I'm referring to in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are directly accessing the method from model like

```
$data = \App\ModelName::methodName();
```

Then your method should be static.

if your method is not static you can access like,

```
$model = new \App\ModelName();
$data = $model->methodName();
```

Comment: Turned out I just had'nt instantiated my model before trying to access it......... do I need to say that I'm new to this? Anyways, thank you for your help!